# VS Code Extension: How to automatically add references and using statements in .csx files

Tags: visual-studio-code, reference, using

I am trying to write a VS Code extension where it would automatically add a set of reference / using statements to certain files.

For example, if I create a **new file** `test.csx` which will eventually use `testReference.dll`, is there a way to **automatically** reference the .dll file in the .csx **without** using `#r C:\path\to\dll\testReference.dll` in the `test.csx`?

Similar question is that is there a way to **automatically** reference a `using` statement in the .csx **without** using the `using System.test` in the `test.csx`?

If there is no way to do with automatically AND without using the `#r C:\path\to\dll\testReference.dll` or using `System.test`, then is here a way to add the reference / using statement automatically when creating a new file?

Comment: You can try if [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions) can help you automate the addition based on Diagnostic messages or just always available code completions

Comment: @rioV8 Ahh got it. But is it possible for me to have one file to have all references / using statements and the `test.csx` only has to reference that file? Like if I create a file `reference.csx` or somehting like that, can I combine all using and reference statements into one file?

Comment: then you have to look in the C# docs